# Failed to delete secure boot state in Ubuntu - dual boot with Windows 11

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, dual-boot, secure-boot

I have dual booted Ubuntu with Windows 11 and the Wi-Fi adapters were not detected.

So I have done something and they were working but after 2-3 days again the same problem occurred but this time it was showing that Realtek drivers:

[image: But this time it was showing that Realtek drivers]

The Wi-Fi adapter is not detected but it is working fine in Windows 11, so I don't think so there is any hardware problem:

[image: WiFi Adapter not detected but they are working fine in windows 11,So i don't think so there is any hardware problem]

Then I tried to update them using terminal and got to know that as they are proprietary drivers, I will need to have secure boot.

[image: Secure Boot dialog]

Then I followed the step given in this link, [Debian Wiki - Secure Boot](https://wiki.debian.org/SecureBoot).

After confirming MOK password I got this

[image: Failed to Delete Secure Boot State]

I have generated another MOK key but haven't deleted the previous is that a problem. I am a beginner I don't know anything about these keys after googling I came to know that they are stored in firmware. So is it a issue if I have two keys?

Using HP laptop with NVIDIA graphics card and 1 TB HDD:

- one partition is of Ubuntu, and:
- the other is 256 GB SSD for Windows 11

So what should I do now?